# Why is css grid-template-areas not respecting my media query?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is the code. I think it's a silly error, but I can't see it -grr. I've tried many times.

The media query grid-template-areas in my code is

```
". title title ."
". img-1-title img-2-title ."
". img-1 img-2 ."
". img-3-title img-4-title ."
". img-3 img-4 ."
```

but it shows this template in my browser

```
"img-1 title title img-2"
"img-3 img-1-title img-2-title img-4"
". img-3-title img-4-title ."
```

html

```
<section>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="title">Here is a couple of side projects</div>
    <div class="img-1-title">A chat app build with socket.io and node.js</div>
    <div class="arrow-1"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-1"></div>
    <div class="img-2-title">A responsive mock template of a company build with html css and flexboxgrid</div>
    <div class="arrow-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-2"></div>
    <div class="img-3-title">Wikipedia search bar connected to the wikipedia API</div>
    <div class="arrow-3"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-3"></div>
    <div class="img-4-title">Vanilla js calculator</div>
    <div class="arrow-4"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-4"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The reason I redeclare my grid-area is because there is a yellow error in my console if I dont. It works, but I don't like the error, so yea.

css

```
       .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "title"
        "img-1-title"
        "arrow-1"
        "img-1"
        "img-2-title"
        "arrow-2"
        "img-2"
        "img-3-title"
        "arrow-3"
        "img-3"
        "img-4-title"
        "arrow-4"
        "img-4";
        background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
    }

    .title {
        grid-area: title;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: white;
    }

    .img-1 {
        grid-area: img-1;
        background: url("../postimg/chat_app.png") center/cover;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .img-2 {
        grid-area: img-2;
        background: url("../postimg/Web_template.png") center/cover;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .img-3 {
        grid-area: img-3;
        background: url("../postimg/Wiki_viewer.png") center/cover;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .img-4 {
        grid-area: img-4;
        background: url("../postimg/js_calculator.png") center/cover;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .img-1-title {
        grid-area: img-1-title;
    }

    .img-2-title {
    grid-area: img-2-title;
    }

    .img-3-title {
        grid-area: img-3-title;
    }

    .img-4-title {
    grid-area: img-4-title;
    }

    .img-1-title, .img-2-title, .img-3-title, .img-4-title {
        display: flex;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 8px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: white;
        border-top: 3px solid rgb(15, 177, 15);
    }

    .arrow-1 {
        grid-area: arrow-1;
    }

    .arrow-2 {
        grid-area: arrow-2;
    }

    .arrow-3 {
        grid-area: arrow-3;
    }

    .arrow-4 {
        grid-area: arrow-4;
    }

    .arrow-1, .arrow-2, .arrow-3, .arrow-4 {
        display: flex;
        padding: 15px;
        height: 25px;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .fas {
        color: white;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        .grid {
            grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 1fr 200px;
            grid-template-areas: 
            ". title title ."
            ". img-1-title img-2-title ."
            ". img-1 img-2 ."
            ". img-3-title img-4-title ."
            ". img-3 img-4 .";
            background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
        }

        .title {
            grid-area: title;
        }

        .img-1 {
            grid-area: img-1;
        }

        .img-2 {
            grid-area: img-2;
        }

        .img-3 {
            grid-area: img-3;
        }

        .img-4 {
            grid-area: img-4;
        }

        .img-1-title {
            grid-area: img-1-title;
        }

        .img-2-title {
        grid-area: img-2-title;
        }

        .img-3-title {
            grid-area: img-3-title;
        }

        .img-4-title {
        grid-area: img-4-title;
        }

        div.arrow-1, div.arrow-2, div.arrow-3, div.arrow-4 {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I found my problem, I had `<a>` tags before my divs that was messing up the grid, I don't know why I didn't include them in my HTML, I presumed it wasn't the problem, - smacks forehead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just me but everything seems fine to me.
It is changing the media query at 1000px.

[image]

The only thing I would change is to use a grid-gap in order for the images to not clump together. This will improve the look on smaller devices by a lot.

```css
.grid {
  grid-gap: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title" "img-1-title" "arrow-1" "img-1" "img-2-title" "arrow-2" "img-2" "img-3-title" "arrow-3" "img-3" "img-4-title" "arrow-4" "img-4";
  background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
}

.img-1 {
  grid-area: img-1;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/1500/650") center/cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-2 {
  grid-area: img-2;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/1500/500") center/cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-3 {
  grid-area: img-3;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/2500/500") center/cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-4 {
  grid-area: img-4;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/1500/600") center/cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.img-1-title {
  grid-area: img-1-title;
}

.img-2-title {
  grid-area: img-2-title;
}

.img-3-title {
  grid-area: img-3-title;
}

.img-4-title {
  grid-area: img-4-title;
}

.img-1-title,
.img-2-title,
.img-3-title,
.img-4-title {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(15, 177, 15);
}

.arrow-1 {
  grid-area: arrow-1;
}

.arrow-2 {
  grid-area: arrow-2;
}

.arrow-3 {
  grid-area: arrow-3;
}

.arrow-4 {
  grid-area: arrow-4;
}

.arrow-1,
.arrow-2,
.arrow-3,
.arrow-4 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fas {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 1fr 200px;
    grid-template-areas: ". title title ." ". img-1-title img-2-title ." ". img-1 img-2 ." ". img-3-title img-4-title ." ". img-3 img-4 .";
    background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
  }
  .title {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  .img-1 {
    grid-area: img-1;
  }
  .img-2 {
    grid-area: img-2;
  }
  .img-3 {
    grid-area: img-3;
  }
  .img-4 {
    grid-area: img-4;
  }
  .img-1-title {
    grid-area: img-1-title;
  }
  .img-2-title {
    grid-area: img-2-title;
  }
  .img-3-title {
    grid-area: img-3-title;
  }
  .img-4-title {
    grid-area: img-4-title;
  }
  div.arrow-1,
  div.arrow-2,
  div.arrow-3,
  div.arrow-4 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="title">Here is a couple of side projects</div>
    <div class="img-1-title">A chat app build with socket.io and node.js</div>
    <div class="arrow-1"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-1"></div>
    <div class="img-2-title">A responsive mock template of a company build with html css and flexboxgrid</div>
    <div class="arrow-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-2"></div>
    <div class="img-3-title">Wikipedia search bar connected to the wikipedia API</div>
    <div class="arrow-3"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-3"></div>
    <div class="img-4-title">Vanilla js calculator</div>
    <div class="arrow-4"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
    <div class="img-4"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

I am sry if I misunderstood your question :D

---

The problem might be your browser since you already had problems there.

> The reason I redeclare my grid-area is because there is a yellow error in my console if I dont. It works, but I don't like the error, so yea.

Firefox seems to work fine so you could try to use it. They also have this nice grid-view which shows you the css grid.

For reference my version of firefox is  `Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 (64-Bit)`

Since you are using Chrome I also looked at the problem in Chrome and the files also worked fine on my Chrome version  `Version 68.0.3440.75 (official build) (64-Bit)`

You should probably check your version of chrome and compare it with the list of [supported browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

If you don't know how to check your browser version here is a small guide for most modern web browser. [[LINK]](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001329.htm)

Comment: I was just using plain css and html. What browser are you using? I am currently using firefox. Maybe there is some problem with the compatibility since you said, that your console is throwing errors at you.

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: I need to leave, im going to answer later, I will upvote your answer if your next comment fixed my problem.

Comment: added a bit to my answer regarding the browser question

Comment: My chrome wasn't the latest version, but when I updated it to (Version 68.0.3440.75 (Build officiel) (64 bits)), it still didn't work and still shows the yellow errors. I tried in firefox (same version as yours)  and same result. I gave you a vote for your efforts, thanks.

Comment: I just tried on other pages and it works, something wrong with my portfolio component.